# How to use NodeJS / PhantomJS / CasperJS on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I need to scrape a website form (on-the-fly) which has AJAX and SESSIONS. I did a lot of research and I came across several possible solutions one being Python::Mechanize. I don't know python and cURL alone for `PHP` (from my understanding) cannot handle AJAX or submit forms.

I found what i believe is the possible stack which can lead me to grace :). Problem is that I do not know how to use these packages at all.

1. I downloaded and installed NODEjs and I can call it from cmd. (great)
2. I downloaded and installed PhantomJS (Not sure how to setup the `PATH` so that it is dynamic so I have to manually `cd` in CMD to the `DIR` to get it to load) How can I set this up in Windows 7? Not sure where to point the path.
3. Downloaded CasperJS - put in the DIR

So on phantomjs I was able to run a test file which echos 'hello world' in the CMD prompt. And now I here no clue how to proceed. -Ultimatly i need this to run (on-the-fly) from my webserver - so it needs to be implemented into my webpage. As of now I would like to just run it from CMD and get it to go to a page, submit a form, scrape the results, and write it to a file.

Can someone please explain like a workflow of how I can accomplish this?

CasperJS -> shows this form example. and I would like to implement with my variables, run the script and save the result.

```
casper.start('http://some.tld/contact.form', function() {
    this.fill('form#contact-form', {
        'subject':    'I am watching you',
        'content':    'So be careful.',
        'civility':   'Mr',
        'name':       'Chuck Norris',
        'email':      'chuck@norris.com',
        'cc':         true,
        'attachment': '/Users/chuck/roundhousekick.doc'
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluateOrDie(function() {
        return /message sent/.test(document.body.innerText);
    }, 'sending message failed');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('message sent').exit();
});
```

Comment: is your node server working fine on windows7? and also you are not clear what you want to do just make nodejs phantomjs to work in windows7 or you also want some help with screen scraping using node and phantom ?

Comment: yes i need help in both areas -- as a matter of fact i'm willing to pay :)  i dont know how to work this in from CMD - and I need to eventually implement the script into the webpage to run (dynamically) and to top it off I'm not even sure that these scripts will be able to handle the ladder. '

Comment: This is totally possible in fact I have done something like this using Node+phantom There are lot of things thats not clear like what happens after the form is submitted and things like that and I am not sure what do you mean by Implement the script into the webpage

Comment: here's what i need to do. site [a] form is controlled by AJAX  1. go to site [a] 2. get all form fields by id of form container in site [a] 3. parse the results and dynamically recreate the form on site [b] 4. user makes a selection on form dropdown on site [b] 5. go back to site [a] with `post` of selection from site [b] 6. wait for site [a] to regenerate `AJAX` and scrape data from the new dropdown 7. return the data to site [b] ... (repeat for all fields) see what I mean?

Comment: Yes but its bit confusing though. Just curious why do you want to make this work in a Windows7 machine?

Comment: The windows 7 only applies to setting the `PATH` for PhantomJS -> I don't know how to set it so that it dynamically routes the `PATH` see here: http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!funcunit.phantomjs  - this doesn't make sense to me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17324/discussion-between-fabio-and-kishore)

Answer (score 2):

After you install PhantomJS do next:

1. From the Desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
2. Click Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
3. In the System Properties window click the Environment Variables button.
4. Find PATH variable and click Edit
5. Add PhantomJS path at the end of the variable value (don't forget ; before it)

For now you can use phantomjs from your CMD. 
Ex.: phantomjs c:\mywebsite\with\ajax\dopescript.js

After these steps download CasperJS and put it in PhantomJS folder
`Ex.: c:\phantomjs\casperjs`

Do previous steps for PATH variable for CasperJS (plus \bin at the end)
`Ex.: c:\phantomjs\casperjs\bin`

Try casperjs from CMD.

If it's not working go to batchbin directory in casperjs folder and lunch casperjs.bat

Now try to call CasperJs from this folder. (Works for me)

So for now you should have PhantomJS + CasperJS.

About saving results:

Put this `var fs = require('fs');` at the beginning of your script and call 
  `fs.write('result.html', myData);` where `myData` is data that you need to save.

Here is more information about FS:
[PhantomJS File System](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/)

Comment: if you put casper inside phantom - can you run "casperjs" command from phantom directory? you don't have to change dir when you want to use casper instead of phantom?