# How to run js files with casperJS, phantomJS without giving full filepath in cmd?

Tags: javascript, cmd, phantomjs, casperjs, filepath

After long battle, I installed both CasperJS, PhantomJS. I checked they both work with --version, it works fine!

However, I have to store all my files i want to run with casperjs in the same folder with casper.exe!

If my javascript file is not in same folder, I have to specify full path to it:

```
casperjs C:\Program Files\Desktop\hello_world.js
```

which is incovenient.

How can I run files with casperjs command without giving abs.path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use NodeJS / PhantomJS / CasperJS on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650274/how-to-use-nodejs-phantomjs-casperjs-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put phantomjs.exe inside casperjs\batchbin\ folder and add it to systemPath then you can excute casperjs everywhere.
For example your casperjs folder is under C:\casperjs\
Run the command and you can excute everywhere :

```
setx path -m "%PATH%;C:\casperjs\batchbin"
```

or see the [link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to show you add system path from gui